# GUI to Create Table in Julia

Tags: user-interface, julia

Is there any Pkg in Julia that have a GUI table like uitable in Matlab or any other way to make a table like in Matlab's GUI? Gtk and Tk don't look to have that function.

Comment: As far as I can see (http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/calling-c-and-fortran-code/) julia is able to call C functions from DLLs. If so you can try to create simple wrapper for my Sciter engine (http://sciter.com). In this case you can use HTML tables or other HTML/CSS means for the UI.
There are already Python ( https://github.com/pravic/pysciter ) , Go, etc. wrappers of the engine. You probably will not need all of those. Just basic 10-20 or so functions will be enough.

Answer (score 2):

Julia is in the early stages. Even if it's now evolving very fast, I'm not sure whether there is a tool like you mention.

You could still use any app like GDocs, Excel, and the like and then export it as a `csv` file. Even if it's not guarantied to fit with what you want at 100% it is a good exercise. It is neither the most fast method but it should work:

1) Initialize an empty array

```
myarray = []
```

2) Use a for loop to read the file by lines

```
for line_str in readlines("<pathtomyfile>.csv")
  # parse() should work form most numerical types
  # map() onto the string elements
  # reshape() it to make it a row vector
  # add it to the final array with vcat()
  myarray = vcat(myarray, reshape(map(parse, split(line, ",")), 1,   length(line))
end
```

You can also use `DataFrames` package so there is a method called `readtable("<pathtoyourfile>.csv")`. I'd give it a try!

**UPDATE:**

Please use the following method. It more convenient

```
julia> myarray = readcsv("pathtoexported.csv")
```

Or you can use `DataFrames.jl`